# Align form items in a Form with nested FormItems

Tags: html, css, blazor, antd

I am using ant design in blazor. An issue I am currently having is that in nested `<FormItem>` layout I am not able to align items as a Form. They are currently not inline. Is there any work around? I guess it should be done in some HTML way?

Here is my current code:

```
  <Panel Header="Basic information" Key="1">
    <Form Layout="FormLayout.Horizontal" Model="this">
        <FormItem Label="Record title">
          <Input @bind-Value="@this.Title" />
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem Label="Description 1235465 ">
          <Input @bind-Value="@this.Description" />
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem Label="Content">
          <TextArea Rows="4" @bind-Value="@this.Content" />
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem Label="Date" NoStyle>
          <DatePicker @bind-Value="@this.SelectedDate" ShowTime="@true" OnChange="this.OnDateSelected" />
        </FormItem>
    </Form>
  </Panel>
```

Here how it currently looks like:

[image]

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LabelColSpan` prop on `Form` component, like this:

```
<Form 
   LabelColSpan="6" /* it can be a number between 1-24 */
   ...
>
```

Comment: Did it worked for you? I am trying it one way and another and items are still misaligned

Comment: Ok, I think there can't be nested FormItems, I had to change parent FormItems into div's, then I have used your solution and it seems to be working. Thank you!